# Can I use PHP function in mysql query columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to list the searced movie's infos.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%'";
```

But `$_GET['search']` is modified as url name so the query dosn't give any result.
Can I use the `modurl()` php function in the title column?

I would like something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE modurl(title) LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%'";
```

Comment: You can not use php functions in sql query.

Comment: You can't pass it to MySQL and expect it to get executed, but you can execute it in PHP and then use the result in your query. However, your code is currently _**wide open** to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)_. Don't build queries by sticking strings together. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: What is `modurl()` doing?

Comment: try to get that function value above the query and pass that variable.

Comment: post your url also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[urldecode][1]`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE modurl(title) LIKE '%".urldecode($_GET['search'])."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rishi's answer:

Although you can, it is not recommended to directly put a url query into SQL.
This would allow SQL injection and a security threat to your database.

Instead, you can use prepared statements and parameterized queries. for example:

```
$title = urldecode($_GET['search']);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE :title");
$stmt->execute(array('title' => $title));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

You can read more about SQL injection [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).